# Why is the custom field "Link" type not displaying as a link?

Tags: civievent, custom-fields, custom, hyperlinks

Is there a reason that the "Link" custom field type is displaying as an Input field instead of rendering an A tag with href? I want to the Link type to render a link as a link.

Answer (score 1):

In edit mode it's an input field. In view mode on the contact summary it is a clickable link.